# OpenSSL 1.0.2 SHA1 requirement causing HTTPS compatibility error with Microsoft Edge 119 ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: apache-2.2, https, openssl, microsoft-edge

I encountered the problem described in this [Thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/1144894/https-compatibility-issue-with-chrome-116-117-err-ssl-protocol-error) but with the Microsoft Edge browser version 119, which has been published on November 2, 2023.

The problem only seems to occur on webserver instances with multiple https-enabled virtualhosts, on virtualhosts that are not the one that loads first based on the load order.

The web server is Apache 2.2.31 running on an AIX server, with OpenSSL 1.0.2u.

I've tried to find a quick fix from the client side, similar to the one described in the aforementioned thread with the `chrome://flags/#use-sha1-server-handshakes`  flag, but inside Microsoft Edge this flag doesn't exist.

It does not seem to be feasible in the short term to update the version of OpenSSL to fix the bug with the SHA-1 signature, so at the moment the only workaround we have is that customers do not update their browser version and continue using Microsoft Edge 118 or lower.

I've searched Microsoft in the release notes and haven't found that SHA-1 signatures have been disabled, but considering that the engine is based on the same as Chrome it's possible that they inherited the behavior without being aware.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/DeployEdge/microsoft-edge-relnotes-security
https://msrc.microsoft.com/update-guide

I'm pretty convinced that the behavior is the same since I can reproduce it with the latest versions of Google Chrome, and I fix it with the aforementioned flag. The problem doesn't occur with Mozilla Firefox.

When taking a network capture and analyzing it with wireshark, it is observed that during the handshake the error is returned by the client, with the message `Illegal parameter (47)`.

Any ideas to fix it in the short term?
Maybe some apache directive could help, for example by modifying the enabled cipher suites?

This is the ssl related configuration (please, void jokes about tls1.0 and tls1.1 enabled protocols)

```
SSLEngine on
SSLProtocol -ALL +TLSv1 +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2
SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!DSS
```

EDIT:
In case someone has the same problem and has the possibility to modify the version of the browser, I leave here a page from which to download previous versions of the MS Edge browser
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/business/download?form=MA13FJ

EDIT2 (after thread was closed):
Using the same servers, with the same operating system and the same old and deprecated version of OpenSSL but using Apache 2.4.32 it seems to be solved.

In case it helps anyone, I leave here as a reference the appearance of the handshake when the error occurs and when it works correctly.

[Network capture aspect when failure occurs.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JahJP.png)

[Network capture looks like when working properly.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ou1DN.png)

Comment: *It does not seem to be feasible in the short term to update the version of OpenSSL to fix the bug with the SHA-1 signature*  This is not a "short term bug".  Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1):  "Since 2005, SHA-1 has not been considered secure against well-funded opponents; as of 2010 many organizations have recommended its replacement. NIST formally deprecated use of SHA-1 in 2011 and disallowed its use for digital signatures in 2013, and declared that it should be phased out by 2030. As of 2020, chosen-prefix attacks against SHA-1 are practical."

Comment: And OpenSSL 1.0.2 reached EOL [four years ago](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSSL#Major_version_releases).

Comment: Another option to buy you some time would be to place a reverse proxy in front of your applications that is old enough to be able to talk to your application servers and new enough to present secure encryption to the clients. But in the end the only real solution is to update.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider And in five years the complaint will be that the reverse proxy is no longer able to talk to the backend... ;)

Comment: @vidarlo that would be more than enough time to do the upgrades without compromising security ... as long as the proxy-backend connection is properly separated from the regular network segments.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Thank you very much for that constructive response. We will take this into account since we have hardware equipment that could manage the secure tunnel with the users instead of delegating it to the web servers. Right now it is our best option

Comment: @GeraldSchneider *that would be more than enough time to do the upgrades without compromising security*  That has not been demonstrated.  The OP's stack has been running with [three 9.8-level security vulnerabilities](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-45/product_id-66/version_id-557570/Apache-Http-Server-2.2.31.html?page=1&cvssscoremin=0&order=3&trc=11) for **six years**.  The update process here isn't *broken*, it flat-out doesn't even exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## You have to upgrade.

This is not a short term bug - it's a *feature*. It's not a mistake that google disabled SHA-1 based signatures. It's because such signatures are widely considered weak and [attacks have been demonstrated](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/60640/does-shattered-actually-show-sha-1-signed-certificates-are-unsafe).

In addition you're running [wildly outdated software](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-45/product_id-66/version_id-557570/Apache-Http-Server-2.2.31.html).

In short: Update your server. This has been on the horizon since roughly 2010. Don't expect the world to stop moving.

> so at the moment the only workaround we have is that customers do not update their browser version and continue using Microsoft Edge 118 or lower.

Hey $customer, are you willing to not upgrade your browsers to save us some work? Sure, it'd expose you to some security problems, but it would save us some hours upgrading...

Comment: I know that we are using old software, in fact right now we have an active project to update the operating system and the Apache version, but it will still take us a few months. We are looking for a possible faster solution, like the workaround with Google Chrome flag

Comment: *This has been on the horizon since roughly 2010.* More like 2005.  [**SHA-1 Broken**](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2005/02/sha1_broken.html): "SHA-1 has been broken. Not a reduced-round version. Not a simplified version. The real thing."

Comment: Security isn't about *active project*. It's a continuous process. It's not like the software is a version or two behind; It's *years* behind. Apache 2.2 was ***discontinued*** five years ago! Your approach to software patching is broken.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Well, CAB has been eyeing SHA1 based signatures since 2010... :) So arguably *this* issue has been obvious from 2010, while noticing it in 2005 probably required a little more technical insight.

Comment: @vidarlo Well, per [Schneier's later link](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2005/02/cryptanalysis_o.html), the 2005 crack required about 2^69 operations, so only well-funded, state-level actors would have been able to exploit it, and I'm not sure it was a universal crack - it might only be useful for creating collisions for a very small set of inputs.  Today?  All such systems are probably engaged in cryptocurrency mining...

Comment: @vidarlo At no time have I indicated that it is a browser bug, I understand that the change has been made for security reasons. The bug seems to be in the openssl version as indicated in the thread I mentioned. If there is only one virtualhost, despite using that prehistoric software, everything works correctly. Anyway, thanks for the response, it will help other administrators who have the possibility of making that update.

Comment: @EnriqueSM *The bug seems to be in the openssl version,,,*  There's no bug here.  At all.  You're running unsupported, outdated software that doesn't support new requirements in some configurations - that's not a bug.   You're lucky it works in any configuration.  Quit making excuses - you haven't told your customers the reason they're having problems is you're running software with 6-year-old vulnerabilities that haven't been patched, have you?  If your organization is hiding that from your customers, they haven't been doing their job.  For years.

Comment: @AndrewHenle The ability to use https with multiple virtualhosts is even older than the version of OpenSSL in use. Maybe you don't consider it a bug because it has already been resolved in newer versions, but others do consider it a bug. You also do not know the reasons why that outdated version continues to be used, the easy option is to say that it has not been worked on properly, but thank you for destroying the work of hundreds of people with your comments. In any case, I'm just trying to find a solution for that inefficient work that has been going on for so many years.

Comment: @EnriqueSM My comments are nothing compared to how your customers would view this - if you've told them the truth about why their Edge browsers no longer work with your service and why they have to reduce security on the Chrome browsers.  And are you **really** trying to say this organization of yours has "hundreds of people", but couldn't make the time to update end-of-life software with serious security vulnerabilities for more than six years?  And again - **this is not a bug**.  Failing to support pre-RFC9155 TLS before RFC9155 even existed **is not a bug**.

Comment: RFC 9155
Deprecating MD5 and SHA-1 Signature Hashes in TLS 1.2 and DTLS 1.2. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9155.html

Comment: @EnriqueSM So maybe you should install software from at least Dec 2021 to support something that didn't exist until that date?  And not make excuses for running software that was EOL'd in 2017 when that old software fails to work when the standards that old code was designed to operate under are changed?

Comment: The thing here is that it isn't like you're *a little* behind with versions. You're 6+ years behind, and haven't maintained your environment. Well, now it's payback time for that; what could have been smooth causes interruptions because of the accumulated technical debt.

Comment: Since someone has considered that this thread should be closed and they have not given me the option to validate the answer or put my own, I leave it commented here, since I know that I am not the only one affected and maybe it will help someone who stops by and reads it. With the same servers, and the same version of openssl 1.0.2u (yes, deprecated years ago), but using apache 2.4.32 it seems that the problem does not reproduce. Now during the handshake, in the "Server Key Exchange" step the web server is using Signature Algorithm: rsa_pkcs1_sha256 (0x0401) instead of rsa_pkcs1_sha1 (0x0201)